# shift+alt+F is not formatting embedded HTML in react correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, visual-studio-code

When I am woriting code in vs code editor. one time I have press Shif + Ctrl + F key.
Then in js file I m writing something then save it formate wrong or someting other.
I have using VS Code editor version: 1.60.2

I am wring code.
[image]

Then I have save document. It look like follwing image. (At onetime I have press Shif + Ctrl + F key in vs code editor )

[image]

Comment: Shift+Ctrl or Shift+Alt? Please update the title or question body for correctness and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is wrong. You have JavaScript selected:

[image]

But when you're using JSX syntax, that's not standard JavaScript - you need to specify it by selecting JavaScript React, which looks like:

[image]

for the correct formatter to do its work properly.